# JavaScript: difference between typeof(var)==='undefined' vs =='undefined'?

Tags: javascript, comparison, undefined, typeof

Perhaps a somewhat theoretical question, but to check if a variable exists or not, this is most commonly advised:

`typeof(var)==='undefined'` or `typeof(var)!=='undefined'`

How does this differ from `typeof(var)=='undefined'` (or `typeof(var)!='undefined'`) ?

I mean `===` vs `==`. Or `!==` vs `!=`. I know this normally means comparison of **type** as well as value, but in this case, `typeof(something)` always evaluates to a string, right?

Is there any scenario possible where `typeof(var)==='undefined'` and `typeof(var)=='undefined'` are *not* the same?

Comment: The answer on this thread should help to clarify...    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons

Comment: You're right. Some people like to always use `===` to be consistent (or they have read somewhere that `==` is pure evil and should be avoided at all cost).

Comment: Quick note: `typeof` is an operator, not a function. You can omit those parenthesis.

Comment: Yes, the typeof operator always returns a String as mentioned here: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_type_conversion.asp. I can't think on a scenario where does two scenarios are not the same only because typeof returns string

Answer (score 0):

There is really no difference thus typeof returns a string.

Use `===` and `!==` when you want to avoid automatic conversions.

Examples:

```
alert(1!='1')//false
alert(1!=='1')//true
alert('1'!='1')//false
alert('1'!=='1')//false
alert(true==1)//true
alert(true===1)//false
```

Answer (score 0):

The '===' and '!==' operators are a bit faster, so in most cases, these should be used instead of '==' or '!='.

Answer (score -1):

As for the `!=` part, the `!` is to be taken as a NOT. `typeof var !=='undefined'` => `if typeof var is not undefined`

Comment: Thanks, yes I knew, I just wondered about the difference between `typeof var !== 'undefined'` and `typeof var != 'undefined'`, but apparently there is none.

Comment: A matter of preference, here merely. BUT in some languages, it's proper to use `==` in an if statement, as that checks, while just a single `=` sets (always return strue in the if). Good to tell them apart.